# Does the ring of polynomial of infinitely many variables $\mathbb{R} [ x_1 , x_2 , \ldots ]$ have one maximal ideal or infinitely many?

Tags: ring-theory

I know that $R:= \mathbb{R} [x_1 , x_2 , \ldots ]$ is non Noetherian, i.e. there is a increasing chain of ideals $\{ I_n \}_{ n \in \mathbb{N} }$such that $I_n \subsetneq I_{n+1}$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and furthermore, I know that given any ideal $I$, we can find a maximal ideal $M$ such that $I \subset M$.

Can I use this to answer this? Can someone drop me some hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:  $\mathbb R[x_1]$ is a quotient, and the maximal ideals in this quotient correspond to some of those in your big ring.  Does $\mathbb R[x_1]$ have one maximal ideal or does it have infinitely many?

Comment: Thanks. An ideal generated irreducible polynomial in maximal in $\mathbb{R}[x_1]$ and there is a surjective homomorphism from $R$ to $\mathbb{R}[x_1]$.Since there are infinitely many irreducible polynomial in $R[x_1]$ , by the correspondence theorem, there must be infinitely many maximal ideals in $R$. Is this line of reasoning, correct?

Comment: @AshishK yes, well said.

Answer (score 1):

There are infinitely many maximal ideals. Indeed, for any real number $r$, the ideal $(x_1+r,x_2,x_3,x_4,...)$ is maximal (of course, $r$ could be added to other variables also, while still yielding a maximal ideal).